# Can I freely rearrange the controlled-shift gates in this 3-qubit circuit?

Tags: quantum-gate, circuit-construction

Consider a fixed set of gates of the kind $\land_n(P_{\varphi})$. With $P_{\varphi}$ being a relative phase shift gate by $\varphi$.

Can I assert that any permutation of that set is equivalent?

Example:

[image]

Can I rearrange this circuit at my liking and always get the same evolution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, as long as you change the order of the gates without changing the qubits on which each gate acts.

**Proof:** All phase gates are represented by diagonal unitary matrices. If $A$ has a diagonal matrix then controlled-$A$ also has a diagonal matrix. Therefore, all gates in your set of gates have diagonal matrices. Conclusion follows from the fact that diagonal matrices commute.